# get index of selcted item in QListView in python

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlistview

```
self.listOfSongs = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralwidget)
self.listOfSongs.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 160, 191, 192))
self.listOfSongs.setObjectName("listOfSongs")
self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
self.listOfSongs.setModel(self.model)
self.updateList()
```

```
def updateList(self):
   self.model.clear()
   for x in self.table:
      item = QtGui.QStandardItem(x)
      self.model.appendRow(item)
```

I hope someone can tell me how to get the item or the index of the item that I choose by selecting or click on?
Using lib pyQT5 in python

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`QStandardItemModel` is a model so you can use all the methods of `QAbstractItemModel`. You can iterate over rows and use the `item()` method to get the *QStandarItem* associated with each index, and then use the `text()` method of the *QStandarItem* to get the text.

```
    self.listOfSongs = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralwidget)
    self.listOfSongs.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 160, 191, 192))
    self.listOfSongs.setObjectName("listOfSongs")
    self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    self.listOfSongs.setModel(self.model)


    for text in ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"]:
        it = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
        self.model.appendRow(it)

    self.listOfSongs.clicked[QtCore.QModelIndex].connect(self.on_clicked)

def on_clicked(self, index):
    item = self.model.itemFromIndex(index)
    print (item.text())
```

on click:

[image]

Comment: I did it in the end like that:
To get the data:
self.song = self.listOfSongs.currentIndex().data()  
To get the index:
self.index = self.listOfSongs.currentIndex().row()

tnx for your answers